# what is the principle to install the wordpress in my computer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed Wordpress on my pc, but I don't know how it works, here are my steps:

1. Install  WAMP: Donwload bitnami wamp stack and click install.
2. Create a MySQL database for wordpress: Input `local/phpmyadmin` in firefox ，to create new database and write down the password.
3. Download wordpress, copy web-config-sample.php into web-config.php, and fill the blanks.
4. Copy wordpress (and all the files in it)
   C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\wordpress
5. At last go to  `local\wordpress` in firefox, and start the installation

**web-config.php:**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'sql_wordpress');   
define('DB_USER', 'root');   
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'haha');  
define('DB_HOST', 'local:3306');
```

I named the database sql_wordpress and set password `haha`.

I want to know why the installation begin ,when i input  local\wordpress in firefox ?
What is the principle for the installation?

Comment: What you are asking could go from a simple "You are executing the installation script" to what is a server, a tcp connection, http, php... What exactly don't you understand about the process?

Comment: where is the installation script?

Comment: This is not a support forum for setting up servers. If you don't know how to do it, buy some space at a PHP webhost and install your Wordpress there.

Comment: Niels B. please read the question before posting comments. OP seems to know how to install Wordpress, but wants to understand details.

Comment: I hope understands from the details I provided below ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDITED ANSWER**    You will encounter several sub-steps at step 5
>
> Assuming that your folder is named as `wordpress`
>
> The Installation Script can be located at 
>   `wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php`
>
> It'll begin with the creation of config file! You should note that you
>   have already created the `setup-config.php` file
>
> **At Step 1:** It'll setup the pre-requisites such as database name/username/host/password and table prefix with which all the
>   associated tables will be created.It'll move on to
>
> `wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2`
>
> **At Step 2:** After you provide correct details regarding the database,then it moves on to the basic information needed about the
>   website such as website title.This script can be found in
>
> ```
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php
> ```
>
> After you perform these steps it'll take you to the admin dashboard.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Your question is not clear to me but you seem to ask like why a wordpress installation occurs at step 5 ?

> **What is WAMP ?**
>
> WampServer is an easy to use web server package
>   that allows you to configure Apache, MySQL and PHP in your local
>   machine to match that of your live web server.
>
> **What is Wordpress ?**
>
> Wordpress is a CMS(content-management system) based on PHP and MySql
>   that runs on a hosting service

So you have to install WAMP to HOST the wordpress.Wamp contains PHPMyadmin for PHP and MySql database

In the steps above you configured your PHPmyAdmin and MySQl to be associated with wordpress.

At Step 5,when you goto -> `localhost/website`(or the foldername which contains the wordpress zip files), you have to manually configure the wordpress files so that it can access the database and other stuffs it needs to function properly.

Comment: my question is exactly that why a wordpress installation occurs at step 5 ?

Comment: in step5 ,which installation script  make the installation happen?

Comment: answer has been edited. check it out